# Remove sub string from a string

Tags: c#

I have a string

str="234,555,456,222,666,"

Please don't use regular expressions...
If I remove any value then the final result of string should seperated values with ','.

1) First/any where in the middle value in String then I have to remove "value and , "
    Example  234  --> 234,
     2) If its last value in the string then I have to remove ", and value and , "

For Example
If I want to remove 456 then 
   So the final string like
                str="234,555,222,666"

Thnx

Comment: What is the driving principle? Code clarity/maintainability, or performance?

Comment: @Aviad P.: Possibly homework :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
string input = "234,555,456,222,666,";

string output = input.Replace("456", "").Replace(",,", ",").TrimEnd(',');
```

Comment: Didn't check my code before writing it. Stupid, you're right. It's `TrimEnd` by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the easy way...

```
 str="234,555,456,222,666,".Remove("456").Replace(",,",",").TrimEnd(",".ToCharArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this, using Linq?

```
string s = "234,555,456,222,666,";
string[] sa = s.Split(new []{','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

string s2 = String.Join(",", sa.Where(x => x!="456").ToArray());
```

s2 becomes the requested result.